# DIV AREA ease in like drop down menu (display:none to display:block)

Tags: javascript, html

This is in PHP page in multiple places and works fine. An img link that pops down the div content area, then pops back up on another click - with a small img button at the bottom of the area to also pop the content back up/away. I am trying to find a way for the  area to ease down like a fancy menu instead of just appearing instantly.

Is this possible to do, or am I beating my head against a wall for nothing?
Any help would be greatly appreaciated! -thx!

```
<head>
function toggle(id) {
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
}
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggle('unique_name')"><img ...></a>
<div id="unique_name" align="center" style="display:none;">
<span> -content- </span>

<div align="center"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('unique_name').style.display='none';"><img src="/path/file-name.png" width="150" alt="Hide"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript it would go something along the lines of this create a variable `var _opened = false` then with the `onClick()` `if(_opened == false){..do animation then.. _opened = true} else { .. closing animation then.. _opened = false}` you'll have to look up how to do the animation but thats the framework for it.

For the animation you can't use the block style as there's no in between block state you'd have to append the image in to the `<div>` then change the height of it, in jquery something like this `$('id of element').animate({height : "chosen height"});`